# .htaccess rewriting with GET parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to set up .htaccess file for rewrting url like example.com/33 to example.com?id=33 (example.com/index.php?id=33) and example.com/Test to example.com?name=Test (example.com/index.php?name=Test)

My htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But when I goto url example.com/33 it will redirect me to index.php, but id parameter doesn't exist. Where can be the problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot :)

Comment: Its great! you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of this answer

Answer (score 0):

Have 2 rewrite rules, one for digits (id) and another for `name` parameter:

```
RewriteEngine On

# ignore all existing files and directories for rewriting     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! You really helped me :)